# Trying to move elements into empty arrays. Code runs, but nothing is being returned

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm very new to coding and I've been trying to practice arrays and storing new elements into empty arrays. this code runs, but nothing comes back. what am I doing wrong?

```
const myArr = [2,2,3,4,4,5]
const evenArray = [];
const oddArray = [];

for (let i=0; i<myArr.length; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0)
    myArr.push(evenArray[i])
    return evenArray
} if (myArr[i % 2 !== 0]) {
    myArr.push(oddArray[i])
}
    return oddArray

console.log(evenArray)
```

Comment: Why do you have a return statement if it's not a function?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of problems with your code.

For example:

You are trying to use `return` out of a function.

You are pushing into `myArr`, instead of *even* or *odd* arrays..

You are also not correctly using the curly braces. Here is how you should do it.

```js
const myArr = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];

const evenArray = [];
const oddArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
  if (myArr[i] % 2 === 0) {
    // even
    evenArray.push(myArr[i]);
  } else {
    // odd
    oddArray.push(myArr[i]);
  }
}

console.log({ evenArray });
console.log({ oddArray });
console.log({ myArr });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Main problems with how you are writing your code:

- Return statement not within function
- Not using if statements correctly

Here is a solution:

```
      const myArr = [2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5];
      const evenArray = [];
      const oddArray = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
        if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0) {
          evenArray.push(myArr[i]);
        } else {
          // We can just use an else statement here because anything thats not even is odd
          oddArray.push(myArr[i]);
        }
      }

      console.log(evenArray, oddArray); // Now that the loop has run console.log the results
```

Note: Stack overflow is not the place to ask questions about the basics of coding! I would recommend checking out freeCodeCamp.org and their YouTube channel because you seem to have problems with the fundamental principals of js.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need return statements. Only save values into new arrays.

```js
const myArr = [2,2,3,4,4,5]
const evenArray = [];
const oddArray = [];

for (var i=0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    if (myArr[i] % 2 == 0) {
       evenArray.push(myArr[i]) //push even elements into evenArray
    }
    if (myArr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
        oddArray.push(myArr[i]) //push odd elements into oddArray
     }
}
console.log(evenArray) //evenArray will have even numbers
console.log(oddArray)  //oddArray will have odd numbers
```

Answer (score 0):

Please share which programming language you're using.

As per your code it seems you are pushing the empty array value to your myArr array. Try using `evenArray.push(myArr[i])` instead of `myArr.push(evenArray[i])`

Comment: The programming language is in the tags